# Performance of Wolfram Mathematica InverseFunction

Tags: performance, wolfram-mathematica

given the constants

```
mu = 20.82;
ex = 1.25;
kg1 = 1202.76;
kp = 76.58;
kvb = 126.92;
```

I need to invert the function

```
f[Vpx_,Vgx_] := Vpx Log[1 + Exp[kp (1/mu + Vgx/(Vpx s[Vpx]))]];
```

where

```
s[x_] := 1 + kvb/(2 x^2);
```

so that I get a function of two variables, the second one being `Vgx`.

I tried with

```
t = InverseFunction[Function[{Vpx, Vgx}, f[Vpx, Vgx]], 1, 2];
```

tested with `t[451,-4]`

It takes so much time that every time I try it I stop the evaluation.

On the other side, working with only one variable, everything works:

```
Vgx = -4;
t = InverseFunction[Function[{Vpx}, f[Vpx,Vgx]]];
t[451]
```

It's my fault? the method is inappropriate? or it's a limitation of Wolfram Mathematica?

Thanks
Teodoro Marinucci

P.S. For everyone interested it's a problem related to the Norman Koren model of triodes.

Comment: My guess is that it first tries to solve symbolically for the inverse, e.g. `Solve[Function[{Vpx, Vgx}, f[Vpx, Vgx]][X, #2] == #1, X]`, which takes a very long time (and I didn't let it finish, either).  You might want to just code the inverse directly with `FindRoot`, if a numerical approximation is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, now
inv[f_, s_] := Function[{t}, s /. FindRoot[f - t, {s, 1}]]
einv = inv[f[x, Vgx], x];
works better.
Now I need some more help to understand how to modify the inv[] function so that einv is function of two variables: Vpx and Vgx.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, my guess is that `InverseFunction` first tries to solve symbolically for the inverse, e.g. `Solve[Function[{Vpx, Vgx}, f[Vpx, Vgx]][X, #2] == #1, X]`, which takes a very long time (I didn't let it finish).  However, I came across a system option that seems to turn this off and produce a function:

```
With[{opts = SystemOptions["ExtendedInverseFunction"]},
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  SetSystemOptions["ExtendedInverseFunction" -> False],
  t = InverseFunction[Function[{Vpx, Vgx}, f[Vpx, Vgx]], 1, 2],
  SetSystemOptions[opts]
  ]];

t[451, -4]
(*  199.762  *)
```

A couple of notes:

1. According to the documentation, `InverseFunction` with exact input should produce an exact answer.  Here some of the parameters are approximate (floating-point) real numbers, so the answer above is a numerical approximation.
2. The actual definition of `t` depends on `f`.  If `f` changes, then a side effect will be that `t` changes.  If that is not something you explicitly want, then it is probably better to define `t` this way:

   ```
   t = InverseFunction[Function[{Vpx, Vgx}, Evaluate@f[Vpx, Vgx]], 1, 2]
   ```

Comment: Seems to work well. I have some glitches that I shall solve tomorrow. I go to sleep (it's 3 AM for me). Thanks again

Comment: No, glitches are more severe than expected.
There are vast regions where the InverseFunction doesn't work.
I did a contour plot and it seems erased (white quite everywhere)
Thanks

Comment: @TeodoroMarinucci (1) A numeric `InverseFunction` uses `FindRoot` (or equivalent) with an arbitrary starting point. That's why I suggested manually using `FindRoot`, but you'd want to have a good heuristic for choosing a starting point. (2) White in a `ContourPlot` often indicates that the value of the function exceeded the automatically chosen `PlotRange`. If you haven't tried it already, try the `ContourPlot` with `PlotRange -> All`, although "white quite everywhere" doesn't give me much hope.

Comment: Yes, no hope.  
Using inv[f_, s_] := Function[{t}, s /. FindRoot[f - t, {s, 10}]] I can reasonably control the algorithm. However I don't know how to choose a starting point when using InverseFunction.  
Alternatively I would like to know ho to deal with two variables in the inv[f_, s_].  
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As my late Theoretical Physics professor said, "a simple and beautiful solution is likely to be true".
Here is the piece of code that works:

```
    mu = 20.82; ex = 1.25; kg1 = 1202.76; kp = 76.58; kvb = 126.92; 
    Ip[Vpx_, Vgx_] = Power[Vpx/kp Log[1 + Exp[kp (1/mu + Vgx/Sqrt[kvb + Vpx^2])]], ex] 2/kg1;  
    Vp[y_, z_] := x /. FindRoot[Ip[x, z] == y, {x, 80}]
```

The "real" amplification factor of a tube is the partial derivative of Ip[Vpx, Vgx] by respect to Vgx, with give Vpx. I would be happier if could use the Derivative, but I'm having errors.
I'll try to understand why, but for the moment the definition
        [CapitalDelta]x = 10^-6;
        [Micro][Ipx_, Vgx_] := Abs[Vp[Ipx, Vgx + [CapitalDelta]x] - Vp[Ipx, Vgx]]/[CapitalDelta]x
works well for me.
Thanks, it was really the starting point of the FindRoot the problem.